# fopen doesnt work if script run by shell_exec

Tags: fopen, lamp

I have a strange issue on my LAMP installation. I have a php script with function that save a log to a file using fopen().
  If I run the script by shell_exec($scriptfilewithpath) nothing happens (it may give some errors but I am not sure how to get it from shell_exec.
If I run the script from the ssh console (sudo php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/script.php ) I get " PHP Warning: fopen(/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/log.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/script.php on line 18" . 
root and bitnami(used to install and set up LAMP) users have full access to script folder.
Any ideas where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You will find the errors in the Apache error log. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#errorlog

Comment: Your script tries to open a file which does not exists. It does not matter, if the user has access, if the file does not exists.

Comment: Ceving - I use option 'a' with fopen which creates new file if it doesnt exist. I also tried creating the file first - same error :/

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).